# Arrange rows in a clustermap using seaborn

Tags: pandas, seaborn, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to order the rows in my heatmap so that rows with more blue at the beginning are one below another and rows with more red in the beginning are beside each other.

I am using the code:

```
sns.clustermap(transpose,cmap="coolwarm",metric="euclidean",method="average",col_cluster=False)
```

the heatmap looks like this: 
[image: heatmap]

I want something like this:
[image: heat_map_wanted]